# Why use coc and not only the single plugins providing code completion for a language?

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-coc

I'm trying to wrap my head around the necessity of the `coc` plugin, since if I have it installed it still needs the `coc-vimtex` plugin for LaTeX support (which I get is necessary since not all languages can be build into `coc`) and this in turn still needs the `vimtex` Plugin.

Why don't just use the `vimtex` Plugin alone (it too offers code completion and all the other stuff)? Or did I get it wrong that I need the `vimtex` plugin to be able to use the `coc-vimtex` plugin?

Comment: Afaik, it’s a “single-point of entry/single-interface” thing, so that instead of an m-to-n problem you have an m-to-1 problem, or something

Comment: Don't quite understand what you mean, but as far as I understand with testing disabling the single extensions and checking what features are missing coc somehow overtakes the completions function of vim and `coc-vimtex` is then needed so that the completion suggestions of `vimtex` are displayed in `coc`, but not sure if this is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advantage of generic plugins such as CoC is that they work for a wide range of filetypes; for example I normally write most of my code in Go and use the Go Language Server for this (via vim-lsc, which is more or less similar to CoC).

This week I did some C programming though, and by just installing the `clangd` language server on my system vim-lsc also works with C files: I can use the same commands, mappings, and so forth that I'm used to from using vim-lsc with Go. I have some configuration for it too; for example `gd` ("go to definition") opens in a new tab *or* reuses an existing tab if it exists, and with a new "vim-c" plugin I would have to learn the commands and mappings for it, as well as set it up how I like.

The advantage of plugins like vimtex is that it can be more tightly integrated with the language since it's language-specific, and that you get an "IDE in a box" which can be convenient at times. vim-lsc isn't quite enough for full Go support, so I also use a little additional Go plugin; but if I would use vim-go (which is much larger and includes everything, similar to vimtex) then I would have to install just vim-go and be done with it.